# Snake game with pygame

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming, and I wanted to start by making a snake game like snake.io. So as you can see by clicking the link below, I created the snake and all its movements, then I made a red border and coded the "health" of the snake, representing them with some upside-down triangles. What is supposed to happen is that each time the snake touches the red border, it should lose half a heart, and its "health" should go down. However, what actually happens is that I can't move anymore as soon as I touch the border, and my health goes down(since my health is printed in the output), but I don't lose any hearts(visually).
[movement code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aW6w.png)
[main part of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zfYX.png)

I tried to change the entire code, but I was not too fond of it, so I switched back. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug, the movement snake bumps into wall and check the status of loop. I can't find your next move if snake touches the walls in the image, so can't judge!

Comment: Hi, I tried to debug but since I'm using pygame it just won't let me, I don't know why. Regarding the next move for the snake it's all in the code, under "#removes health visually and number wise". Thanks anyway